# why does apache2.conf grants access to /usr/share and /serv by default?

Tags: debian, apache-2.4

I am aware of [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/627455/why-do-i-grant-access-to-usr-share-in-apache2-conf), which is very similar to mine, however I am interested in why this is the *default* behaviour.
Since by default the document root is `/var/www/html`, there is, to my knowledge, no way to access the files at `/usr/share`. Hence I don't see the point of allowing access to them.

Apache version 2.4, on Ubuntu Xenial (16.04)

Comment: How about using symlinks? Root directory can also be changed. `/usr/share` is, as the directory naming suggest a place to share files, so why not also share those files via http? `/srv` is another traditional place for serving shared files using different services. Why do you still use Ubuntu 16.04?

Comment: You're right, I din't thought about symlinks. I know the document root can be changed, but I was asking about the default behaviour. I came across this question while doing apache configuration on a vm for a course, which still used xenial. Thanks !

Comment: @paladin If you post your comment as an answer I can mark it as accepted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about using symlinks? Root directory can also be changed. /usr/share is, as the directory naming suggest a place to share files, so why not also share those files via http? /srv is another traditional place for serving shared files using different services.